# animating marginTop on button click

Tags: jquery, css

I'm a Jquery newbie and I'm trying to animate the `.content` div by changing it's `margin-top` when the `#advBtn` is clicked.

this is my code so far.

it animates down but not up.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#advBtn").click(function(){

    if($('.content').css({ marginTop: '0vh'})) {
    $(".content").animate({ marginTop: '10vh'}, 1000);
    }else{
      $(".content").animate({ marginTop: '0vh'}, 1000);
    };
  });
});
```

Can someone please advise me on this?

Comment: show html please

Comment: `if($('.content').css({ marginTop: '0vh'}))` This literally sets the `margin-top` every time. Try `if($('.content').css('margin-top') === '0vh'`

Comment: you should check margin and then add animate, in your case you are adding a css in if condition which returns true and then adding animate top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use in if `marginTop` not `margin-top`
2. check with `px` not `vh`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#advBtn").click(function(){
    if( $('.content').css('marginTop') == '0px' ) {
    $(".content").animate({ marginTop: '10vh'}, 1000);
    }else{
      $(".content").animate({ marginTop: '0vh'}, 1000);
    };
  });
});
```

```css
.content{
margin-top: 0vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">content<div>
<button id="advBtn">animate</button>
```

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I needed to change... px and marginTop... its working now

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for your issue..

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#advBtn").click(function(){

var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('content'));
var marginTop = style.getPropertyValue('margin-top'); 
alert(marginTop);

    if(marginTop=='0px') {
          $(".content").animate({ marginTop: '10vh'}, 1000);
    }else{
      $(".content").animate({ marginTop: '0vh'}, 1000);
    };
  });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class='content' id='content'>This is test content </div>

<input type='button' id='advBtn' value='click'>
```